# Linearize constraints on a truncated variable

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

Let $K$ and $Q$ be two variables, and $Q_\min$ and $Q_\max$ be two parameters. I need a series of linear constraints to define $Q$ vis-a-vis the value of $K$ based on the following rules:

1. If $K \le Q_\min$ then $Q = Q_\min$
2. If $K \ge Q_\max$ then $Q = Q_\max$
3. If $Q_\min \le K \le Q_\max$ then $Q = K$

Comment: Do you have lower and upper bounds on $K$?  Are $K$ and $Q$ integer variables or continuous?

Comment: @RobPratt The variable are continuous, and we should be able to define bounds on $K$ in the form of big $M$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $K_\min \le K \le K_\max$, and introduce binary decision variables $x_i$ for the three cases (reordered as 1, 3, 2), together with linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i &= 1 \tag1\label1 \\
K_\min x_1 + Q_\min x_2 + Q_\max x_3 \le K &\le Q_\min x_1 + Q_\max x_2 + K_\max x_3 \tag2\label2 \\ 
Q_\min \le Q &\le Q_\min x_1 + Q_\max(1-x_1) \tag3\label3 \\
(Q_\min-K_\max)(1-x_2) \le Q - K &\le (Q_\max-K_\min)(1-x_2) \tag4\label4 \\
Q_\max x_3 + Q_\min(1-x_3) \le Q &\le Q_\max \tag5\label5
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} selects exactly one case.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the bounds on $K$ for each case.
Constraints \eqref{3} through \eqref{5} enforce the value of $Q$ for each case.

---

You could alternatively replace \eqref{3} through \eqref{5} with indicator constraints:
\begin{align}
x_1 = 1 &\implies Q = Q_\min \\
x_2 = 1 &\implies Q = K \\
x_3 = 1 &\implies Q = Q_\max
\end{align}

---

Yet another approach is to recognize that $Q$ is a nonconvex and nonconcave continuous piecewise linear function of $K$ and use any formulation for that, such as the ones recommended in the answers to [How to linearize specific range constraints?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6674/how-to-linearize-specific-range-constraints).

Comment: Rob, the RHS of (3) and the LHS of (5) are kaput.

Comment: @prubin Somehow my comment was deleted, but I did correct these.

Comment: I saw your comment before it was deleted (by SecretAgentMan, for unknown reasons).